# Java - Printing new line after ten values in a For loop

Tags: java, for-loop, println, leap-year

I have been trying to make a simple program that will print out the leap years between 2 inputted years. I have made the loop that checks each year to see if it is a leap year and then prints it, but I would like to be able to only show 10 years on each line, not just all the of them on one long line.

So like this:

```
    1004, 1008, 1012, 1016, 1020, 1024, 1028, 1032, 1036, 1040,
    1044, 1048, 1052, 1056, 1060, 1064, 1068, 1072, 1076, 1080,
    1084, 1088, 1092, 1096, 1104, 1108, 1112, 1116, 1120, 1124,
    1128, 1132, 1136, 1140, 1144, 1148, 1152, 1156, 1160, 1164,
    1168, 1172, 1176, 1180, 1184, 1188, 1192, 1196, 1200.
```

instead of this:

```
1004, 1008, 1012, 1016, 1020, 1024, 1028, 1032, 1036, 1040, 1044, 1048, 1052...
```

I have tried various different methods to make this happen, nested for loops etc but at the moment I cant seem to make it happen.  Sorry if it's a stupid question with a simple answer, I haven't been learning Java for very long at all.

Here is my code so far which prints all the years on one line:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYears {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int firstY, finalY;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter start year: ");
        firstY = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter end year: ");
        finalY = kb.nextInt();

        for(; firstY <= finalY; firstY++) {
            if ((firstY % 4) == 0) {
                if ((firstY % 100) == 0) {
                    if ((firstY % 400) == 0 ) {
                        System.out.print(firstY + ", ");
                        firstY++;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.print(firstY + ", ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep track of where you are in the for loop:

    for(int i = firstY; i <= finalY; i++)

 and print a newline if i is divisible by 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do. Simply add an int counter variable, increment it every time that you print out a year. When it reaches a multiple of 10, simply print a new line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYears 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int firstY, finalY, counter;
    counter = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter start year: ");
    firstY = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter end year: ");
    finalY = kb.nextInt();



    for(; firstY <= finalY; firstY++)

    {
        if ((firstY % 4) == 0)

        {
            if ((firstY % 100) == 0)

            {
                if ((firstY % 400) == 0 )

                {
                    System.out.print(firstY + ", ");
                    firstY++;
                    counter++;
                    if (counter % 10 == 0) System.out.println("");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print(firstY + ", ");
            }

        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly.

Comment: @JavaLava If this was the solution, go ahead and mark it as "Accepted Answer" to make it easy for others to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
int count = 0;
for(; startYear <= endYear; startYear++) {
 System.out.print(startYear + ", ");
 count++;
 if(count == 10) {
  count = 0;
  System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an external counter (say `int printed = 0`) to keep track of how many numbers you have already printed. Check in your inner loop whether `printed % 10 == 0` and call `System.out.println()` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use counter to keep track of the loop

```
int counter =0;
for(; firstY <= finalY; firstY++)

    {
        if ((firstY % 4) == 0)

        {
            if ((firstY % 100) == 0)

            {
                if ((firstY % 400) == 0 )

                {
                    if(counter==10) {
                         System.out.println("");
                    }
                    System.out.print(firstY + ", ");
                    firstY++;
                    counter++;

                }
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print(firstY + ", ");
                counter++;
            }

        }
    }
```