# How to arrange printed numbers using loops in processing? i.e. x and y axis in 10's up to a 100

Tags: java, loops, processing

Ok, I know how to print the number up to whatever number but I am having trouble rearranging them.

This is the format I want..

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20


21  22  23...
```

all the way to 100. so, a 10 x 10 grid format.

This is the code I used:

```
size(500,500);
int x, y;
x= 30;
y= 30;

for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
    text(i, x, y);
    x+=30;
}
```

however, it counts to a 100 in a straight line, and I'm not sure how to make 11 appear on the second line.

I have tried if statements, but the result is limited and requires numerous if statements to carry out the function all the way to 100. what do I do and how can the code be more efficient?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Printing new line after ten values in a For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209716/java-printing-new-line-after-ten-values-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the counter is a multiple of 10, increase the y coordinate and move the x coordinate back to the start of the line.

```
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
    text(i, x, y);
    x+=30;
    if(i % 10 == 0){
       x=30; 
       y += 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate it if downvoters would leave a comment.

Comment: Actually, the question is not clear and you code `if(i % 10 == 0) y += 30;` why?. question is just taking about the printing of 10 numbers per line.

Comment: @AshishKarn Because they appear to be coordinates.

Comment: explanation needs to be clear in the answer and now code makes sense after resetting x value. keep It Up..

Comment: The code you used seems interesting but what does the modulus(%) operator do, is it possible if you coud explain the code further please. I will help me understand programming a lot more.

Comment: The remainder operator returns the remainder after dividing. In this case, if the remainder after dividing by 10 is 0, then it is a multiple of 10. The multiple of 10 is always the last number of the line.

Comment: yh, i understand it a lot better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we want to completely eliminate 'IF' statements, then we can rewrite this code as follows.

```
for(int i=0; i<=99; i++) {
    x = 30 + (i % 10) * 30;
    y = 30 + (i/10) * 30;
    text(i+1, x, y);
}
```

Code explanation :

1. In this code, the loop is started from 0 and ends at 99 and for printing, we have used *i+1* so it will print 1 to 100 as expected.
2. For calculation purpose, we have used the value of *i* and for printing, we have used *i+1*. So keep in mind that *i* will be always one less than current number in loop.
3. x is increasing by 30 with each *i* and get resets to 30 when the number is again 11 or 21... and so on. So if we calculate x is in multiple of 30 with the remainder of 10. And when number is 1 it should be initialized to 30. So the formula will be...
   x = 30 + (i % 10) * 30;
4. y is increasing with every 10 numbers as 11 is needs to be printed on the next line. So y is increasing in multiple of 30 with the division of 10. So formula will be...
   y = 30 + (i/10) * 30;

Comment: The code works properly but i don't understand the maths behind it. Could you explain it please. It will make knowledge of programming a lot better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please upvote the answer if the explanation added in the answer itself is enough.